what is a returnURL after successful payPal transaction while using flutter_paypal in flutter mobile app
I am working on paypal transaction in my flutter app by using flutter_paypal package. The thing which I dont understand is how to return back the user to app after successful transaction. The paypal sdk requires a returnUrl but what should this url be in case of mobile app.
I tried to pass a fake url in sdk and than check in onUrlChange if that url is returned than prevent navigation to that url but that does not help
 onUrlChange: (UrlChange change) {
         
            if (change.url.contains(returnURL)) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
          },


Somebody knows the answer? plz help me
